# protractor, on login form sendkeys() are not working. Browser don't displays my value for the form fields

Tags: javascript, forms, authentication, protractor, cucumber

(I'm not using jQuery) Hi! I'm starting with protractor and cucumber and i'm testing a login page.
I'm trying to insert values on a form for the login, but when i lunch the configuration file to lunch the test, Chrome open the login page but don't displays the values that i setted for the required fields.
Clicking on sumbit button, the page should be redirect to another. Can anyone help me? How i have to change my step definition file to make it works? Thank you

I think that there are some problems like in configuration and others.
Here is step definition:

```
 This is my new step definition file:

    Given("I'm on site login page", function () {
            //return pending;
            browser.driver.get('https://www.websiteurl.com/login.html');
            browser.sleep(20000);
            });     

When('I see the submit-button', function () {
        // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
        //var sumbit = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("submit-//wrap.cf.input-formFields")');
 var sumbit = element(by.css('.submit-wrap.cf.input-formFields'));
        expect(sumbit).to.not.be.null;
      });

     When('I filled all the mandatory fields', function () {
            // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
              window.onload = function(){
                  var bookingNumberField = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("variation2-bookingNumber").getText()');
                  var firstNameField = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("variation2-firstName").getText()');
                  var lastNameField = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("variation2-lastNameField").getText()'); 
                  var dobMonth = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("month").getText()'); 
                  var dobDay = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("day").getText()'); 
                  var dobYear = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("year").getText()');
                //  var firstNameField = document.getElementById("variation2-firstName");
                //      var lastNameField = document.getElementById("variation2-lastName");
                   //   var dobMonth = document.getElementById("month");
                  //    var dobDay = document.getElementById("day");
                  //    var dobYear = document.getElementById("year");
                      browser.sleep(1000);
                      //browser.waitForAngular();
                      //browser.executeScript to cut eventually
                      browser.executeScript.bookingNumberField.clear().sendKeys('WJXMHH');
                     browser.executeScript.firstNameField.clear().sendKeys('Mark');
                    browser.executeScript.lastNameField.clear().sendKeys('Altria');
                      element(by.cssContainingText('option', 'March')).click();
                      element(by.cssContainingText('option', '10')).click();
                      element(by.cssContainingText('option', '1991')).click();
                      TermsChkbxLabel = element(by.css("label[for='checkboxb']"));
                      TermsChkbxLabel.click(); 
              }
          }); //loginBtn.click();

     Then('I am able to click on it to login', function () {

   //       var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
   //       ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
   //       var login_b = browser.executeScript('document.getElementById("login-button").click()');
            //var login_b = document.getElementsByClassName("login-button").click();
    //          ptor.sleep(10000); 
    //          var expectedUrl = ptor.getCurrentUrl();
    //          //expect(expectedUrl).toEqual('https://www.websiteurl.com/newpage.html');

           });

     Then('I am able to open the new page', function () {

    var login_b = element(by.css('.login-button'));
            login_b.click();
    //      var ptor = protractor.getInstance();
    //      ptor.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    //      var login_b = document.getElementsByClassName("login-button").click();
    //       ptor.sleep(10000); 
    //       var expectedUrl = ptor.getCurrentUrl();
    //       


        });
```

Here is the protractor conf.js:

```
var seleniumServer = require('selenium-server')
var nightwatchCucumber = require('nightwatch-cucumber')
require('babel-core/register');

var nightwatchCucumberConf = {
    runner: 'nightwatch',
    featureFiles: 'features',
    stepDefinitions: 'features/step_definitions/testing_1_6.js',
    closeSession: 'afterFeature'
};

exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
    framework: 'custom',
    // path relative to the current config file
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
    plugins: [{
        path: require.resolve('protractor-console'),
        logLevels: ['severe']
    }],

    directConnect: true, //chrome only

    jasmineNodeOpts: {},

    onPrepare: function() {},
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome'
    },

    // Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
    specs: [
        'features/*.feature'
    ],

    baseURL: 'https://www.websiteurl.com/login.html',

    cucumberOpts: {
        //require: 'features/step_definitions/**/*.js',
        require: 'features/step_definitions/testing_1_6.js',
        tags: false,
        // format: 'pretty',
        profile: false,
        'no-source': true
    }
};
```

I have this error too: 
[12:57:27] E/launcher - Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
[12:57:27] E/launcher - Error: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.

Comment: Are you using latest chrome driver ?

Comment: How can i check this?

Comment: Now i have this error:
 Then I am able to click on it to login # reali\login_1\node_modules\cucumber\src\support_code_library_builder\define_helpers.js:90
       TypeError: protractor.getInstance is not a function
           at World.<anonymous> 
Here the line error: step_1_6_new.js:62:25)

Comment: Did you make browser to load your protractor script to let browser as script runner,  I really can't find a reasonable explaining your behavior to directly use JavaScript DOM API in protractor script.  Otherwise it will report `document undefined` .

Comment: Thank you for your reply Yong. I'm starting now with protractor and i'm trying to understand how it works. I checked on web and i found this "wrong" way. I edited the questions with my new stepdefinition code. Can you please check it and tell me what i need to change? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Step definition file `testing_1_6.js`:

```
// chai is an assertion library
var chai = require('chai'); 
// chai-as-promised is an helper to handle promise
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised')
chai.use(chaiAsPromised); 
expect = chai.expect;

Given("I'm on site login page", function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://www.websiteurl.com/login.html');
    return browser.sleep(20000);
});

When('I see the submit-button', function() {
    var sumbitBtn = element(by.css('.submit-wrap.cf.input-formFields'));
    return expect(sumbitBtn.isDisplayed()).to.eventually.be.true;
});

When('I filled all the mandatory fields', function() {
    element(by.id('variation2-bookingNumber')).sendKeys('WJXMHH');
    element(by.id('variation2-firstName')).sendKeys('Mark');
    element(by.id('variation2-lastNameField')).sendKeys('Altria')
    element(by.cssContainingText('#month > option', 'March')).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('#day > option', '10')).click();
    element(by.cssContainingText('#year > option', '1991')).click();
    return element(by.css("label[for='checkboxb']")).click();
}); 

Then('I am able to click on it to login', function() {
    return element(by.id('login-button')).click();
});

Then('I am able to open the new page', function() {
    var newPageUrl = 'https://www.websiteurl.com/newpage.html';
    browser.sleep(10000); 
    return expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal(newPageUrl);
});
```

protractor conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',
    getPageTimeout: 60000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 500000,

    framework: 'custom',
    frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

    plugins: [{
        path: require.resolve('protractor-console'),
        logLevels: ['severe']
    }],

    directConnect: true, //chrome only

    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    },

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome'
    },

    specs: [
        'features/*.feature'
    ],

    cucumberOpts: {
        require: [
            'features/step_definitions/testing_1_6.js'
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited my question, please check if this is the right way. Thank you

Comment: Now i'm using this tutorial, but here is not used cucumber. I can see only jasmine with describe and it blocks. How they can work togheter? I have to use specs and step definition files togheter? How?Sorry for the questions, but i thought that i had to write feature file, then launching protractor conf.js i could have to select and copy Given, when, then blocks returned by terminal after the launch of the conf file, and then drag these blocks to step definition file, filling the blocks with the codes related to the actions. But in this way i don't use specs file. Can you help me to understand?

Comment: this is the url to the protractor tutorial https://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial

Comment: you need to learn what's cucumber and cucumber for javascript at here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cucumber, and the bridge for protractora and cucumber at here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-cucumber-framework

Answer (score 0):

browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);

Comment: even i had the same issue and where i used the above command in my step definition file it worked for me

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your answer. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below your post.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).